# matlab - graph plotting

Tags: matlab

how to do curve fitting ??
i tried plot(cfit,x,y) and it didn't work??

Answer (score 2):

If available have a look at the Curve Fitting Toolbox. You can start it using the command `cftool`. Please elaborate your problem.